# How to add subdomains to Google App Engine with Flask and show different content at site and sub-domain?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask

We have a site developed with Flask using Google App Engine. So we have naked domain mysite.com (which redirects to www.mysite.com) and subdomain www.mysite.com

Now we want to add another subdomain user.mysite.com, so we added it to App Engine Custom domains and registrar without any issues.

BUT we are seeing the same copy of web-site at user.mysite.com as a www.mysite.com (all same pages, just subdomain user. instead of www.)!

How can we show another pages at user.mysite.com (like Hello world!), not the same pages as at www.mysite.com?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is built-into Flask, as `Blueprints`:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/

This does a good job of explaining the `Blueprint` setup for subdomains:

http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html

For some simple cases, you could just test the `request`.  Flask has that built-in, too:

```
@app.before_request
def check_subdomain():
    '''
    This runs before all requests
    '''
    if "user." in request.environ.get('HTTP_HOST'):
        SOME_GLOBAL = 'user'
        return None
```

But, sounds like you want to use `Blueprints`.  It is a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to deploy the dispatch.yaml file as explained in [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dispatchref). By this way, you can route requests to your subdomains to a specific service based on the hostname in the URL.

For your specific case, this could be the dispatch.yaml file:

```
dispatch:
  # For www. subdomain.
  - url: "www.mysite.com/"
    service: [www-subdomain-frontend-service]

  # For user. subdomain.
  - url: "user.mysite.com/"
    service: [user-subdomain-frontend-service]
```